# Exporting each spatial bookmark to jpeg using arcpy gives IndexError?

Tags: arcpy, data-frame, bookmarks, indexerror

I have some spatial bookmarks in my MXD file and i want to export each and every bookmark as one jpeg file. I have found below code but it is giving an error.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\SOFTWARE\Python\test.mxd")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "test")[0]

for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, data_frame=df):

    df.extent = bkmk.extent

    outFile = r"C:\SOFTWARE\Python\Out\\" + bkmk.name + ".jpg"

    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, outFile, df)

del mxd

After running above code, it is giving error as 

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "test")[0]
```

---

> IndexError: list index out of range

How do I export each bookmark as jpeg with the above code?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your data frame is not called 'test' so the call is returning an empty list.

This answer explains a similar call in a bit more detail: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80237/43

If you are adventurous, try:

```
 df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '')[0]
```

This will return all the data frames in your MXD, then select the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the data frame is named "test".

The second argument in `df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "test")[0]` should be the name of the data frame.

Comment: yes. my data frame is not test. Its Test1. once i changed, it works